# How to set maxDate to datepicker using momentjs and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to set max date to datepicker using moment but not working. In the below code only working highlight dates but I want to set max date. I do not know how to set it. If anyone know please help me to find the solutions.

```
ver dateeventPicker=document.getElementById('datepickerid');

dateeventPicker.addEventListener('_change',function(){

let deliverydate = new moment(dateeventPicker.value).add(2,'days')._d;

dateeventPicker.highlightDate = deliveryDate;


})
```

Comment: when you are initializing your datepicker object, at that time you can set max date of your datepicker.
`$("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date(2019, 10, 31) });`

Comment: Do not use datepicker({  function. Can you do using moment?

Comment: then how did you initialized your date control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work I guess

> Here are 5 number of days you want to extend

```
<input type ="date"   min={moment().add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD")} max={moment().add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD")}  />
```

Comment: I have asked for maxDate and minDate

Comment: It is better if you use momentjs

Comment: Yes Updated this new code with moment.js. Seems like this will work for you

Comment: Thanks but I am expecting by javascript because that datepicker is global component so I have only id